# Silverlight ItemsControl displaying one item at a time?

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

I'm looking for a good way to display one item out of a collection at a time in Silverlight, without showing a UI for selecting an item. This would be like a TabControl without the tabs, or a combobox without the drop-down.

Right now we are using a TabControl styled to hide the tabs, but that feels like a hack. Is there a more natural way to do this in Silverlight?

Here are the features I'm looking for:

- Display only the selected item.
- Don't display a UI for selecting an item. (Selection will be changed based on user actions in a different part of the app's UI.)
- Data binding to a collection of viewmodels.
- Using a DataTemplate to display a view for each viewmodel.
- Preserving the state of the view for each selected item. (For example, suppose that inside our one-item-at-a-time control, we display a tree of options for the selected item. I'd like the expanded/collapsed state of the tree nodes to be separately tracked for each item.)

I've tried just using a ContentPresenter bound to the selected item:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedItem}">
  <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <MyUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

But this seems to use a single instance of MyUserControl, rebinding the same instance to different viewmodels as the SelectedItem changes. This means state such as whether or not tree nodes are expanded is not tracked separately per selected item.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple to do.

First step is to use a ListBox, supply the datatemplate, viewmodel collection and bind the selected item like you're already doing.

The step you want (hiding all non selected items) merely needs you to create an ItemContainerStyle. This style has a VisualStateGroup you want to pay attention to, with two states "Selected" and "Unselected". Within the Unselected state you want to set the LayoutRoot to collapsed and within Selected you want the LayoutRoot to be visible.

If you've got Blend this'll take you about 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this approach first. I've got Blend, but my knowledge of Blend extends only about as far as copying a control template. I'll try it out :).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it needs some few work:

you create a class which extends System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector which is the base class for objects which have:

- A collection bound to
- A selectedItem

you set a Grid as ItemsPanel and as ItemTemplate a DataTemplate which fills the whole grid, but is default hidden (or no opacity). A trigger in the DataTemplate on the IsSelected Property hides/showes the Item.

Just one possibility

Comment: Thanks! This also sounds like a good solution. I'll take a look at the customizing the ItemsPanel and using a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you must have access to a SelectedItem propery on the control itself? If you can move the logic of handling the selected item (such as unselecting, returning which item is selected etc.) to the view model you could just use an ItemsControl with a Grid as ItemsPanel. Then in the ItemTemplate you could put MyUserControl. MyUserControl would have its Visibility property bound to a property on the data item with a converter in between. Then you would set IsSelected to true on the data item instead of the UI control, and the corresponding instance of MyUserControl would be shown.

Comment: Thanks! No, I don't actually need to have access to the SelectedItem property on the control. In the code snippet above, I'm binding to a property "SelectedItem", but that's a view model property. I'll look into binding the Visibility property.